Printing hindi text with bluetooth printing device from Android kotlin
Problem:
English fonts are getting printed. Hindi print's are with output as ### by printing device.
Already tried below ways :

String covert in image working but print working very slow.
Using hindi ttf file.
Some printer String to image showing different font.
Tried libraries like (implementation 'com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.1.0')

I tried with so many library but not getting hindi print.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
